# Blender hanging when using threading cond.wait() in python

Tags: python, animation, files

I have this code that iterates over a lot of .obj files, applies some properties, plays the animation, then write some information about it to a file

```
for filename in glob.iglob(source_dir+'\**', recursive=True):
    if os.path.isfile(filename) and filename.endswith(".obj"): # filter dirs
        
        # Import the next clothing mesh
        imported_object = bpy.ops.wm.obj_import(filepath=filename)
        new_mesh = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
        
        ... # Apply cloth, translate it, resize it...
        
        # Clear last handler (Used if script is ran multiple times)
        bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()
        
        # Multithread lock
        condition = threading.Condition()
        callback_done = False
        
        # Define callback
        def stop_playback(scene):
            #nonlocal callback_done
            if scene.frame_current == 60:
                
                ... # Get mesh data
                
                # Stop simulation
                bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel()
                
                # Write data cloud data to file          
                with open(output_file, "w") as f:
                    f.write(data)
        
                print(f"Wrote {file_name} data to : {output_file}\n")
                
                # Release lock
                with condition:
                    callback_done = True
                    condition.notify()
                
        bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(stop_playback)
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()
        

        # Wait for callback to finish then perform next iteration
        with condition:
            while not callback_done:
                condition.wait()
            callback_done = False
```

I have the handler "stop_playback" which I need to run after the simulation/animation is finished so it can finish writing to the file. But I can not start the next iteration of the loop until the callback has finished writing to the file because then variables get all mixed up and bad things happen. I tried to use condition variables so the main loop thread waits until the stop_playback thread has set `callback_done = True` thereby continuing to the next iteration. Thing is, this code just causes blender to hang and white screen me. I am really not sure what is wrong or how to work around this.

If requested I can share the entire code, I cleaned it up and removed unnecessary things for this post. If your curious I need to batch process thousands of .obj files after applying a cloth sim to them. I will end up doing this in headless mode but want to get it working here first.